# Bluetooth: PAN connection refused (111)

Tags: windows, bluetooth, ipod-touch, debian-based

I tried to set up a PAN connection with both my windows 8.1 desktop computer and iPod 4g. Both attempts came up with this error:

```
$ sudo pand –c xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx -n

pand[5029]: Bluetooth PAN daemon version 4.99
pand[5029]: Connecting to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
pand[5029]: Connect to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx failed. Connection refused(111)
```

Does anyone know how to possibly fix this?

-I am using a Debian based distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue. Make sure the PAN node trusts your PAN user device. (Are you sure you paired properly? Were you prompted for the code?)